# Encrypted Import file Archive duration

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, import

I would like to know what will happen when a file is being decrypted in the safehouse then the data will be imported to the DataExtension, what is the purging or archiving duration to destroy that file. Is it done after the import to the DataExtension or it will be archived for certain period?